# HTML img scaling

Tags: html, image-scaling

I'm trying to display some large images with HTML img tags. At the moment they go off the edge of the screen; how can I scale them to stay within the browser window?

Or in the likely event that this is not possible, is it possible to at least say "display this image at 50% of its normal width and height"?

The width and height attributes distort the image -- as far as I can tell, this is because they refer to whatever attributes the container may end up with, which will be unrelated to the image. I can't specify pixels because I have to deal with a large collection of images each with a different pixel size. Max-width doesn't work.

Comment: Keep in mind that its **not** recommended to send huge images and make them small with css. It's better to have different versions of the same image to save bandwidth and to make the page more responsive (even if the image will look small, the full image will be sent).

Comment: rwallace, are you using .net or PHP or something other than pure HTML?

Comment: Image file size doesn't matter, there is no requirement in the case I'm looking at to be frugal with bandwidth. I am using PHP, but the HTML solution works.

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Only set the `width` or `height`, and it will scale the other automatically. And yes you can use a percentage.

The first part can be done, but requires JavaScript, so might not work for all users.

Comment: Please, please, please note that doing this on massive images will result in long download times for pages that shouldn't have long download times. It's always better to actually resize the image if possible.

Comment: Thanks! It turns out your solution of only setting the width not only works for correct scaling, but actually also does the first part just by setting the width to 100%.

Comment: @ceejayoz I agree, but that is not what he is asking.

Comment: @ceejayoz I'm wondering, why does it take longer? Doesn't it have to resize when it displays it for both situations? Or are you saying manually resize the actual image and change the file?

Comment: @Abdul I'm saying a 3,000x3,000 pixel 5MB image shouldn't be used in a 100x100 pixel slot in your website.

Comment: A trick that ive learned is by setting max-height and max-width. If you don't want the height to be larger than a certain size or the same for the width then this is definitely a good idea. The image won't grow larger than the constraints of the boundary. Ive had use cases where setting width or height didn't work. I had to set the max-height/max-width and let the image show depending on which boundary it hit first.

Answer (score 32):

I know that this question has been asked for a long time but as of today one simple answer is:

```
<img src="image.png" style="width: 55vw; min-width: 330px;" />
```

The use of **vw** in here tells that the width is relative to 55% of the width of the viewport.

All the major browsers nowadays support this.

Check this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).

Comment: `vw` was a lifesaver for me, the other methods did not work for the image at hand.

Answer (score 31):

CSS is enough:

```css
img {
    width : desired_width;
    height: auto; /*to preserve the aspect ratio of the image*/
}
```

Answer (score 8):

### No Javascript required.

IE6 Internet Explorer 6

Percent only works for the width of an element, but `height:100%;` does not work without the correct code.

CSS

```
html, body { height:100%; }
```

Then using a percentage works properly, and dynamically updates on window resize.

```
<img src="image.jpg" style="height:80%;">
```

You do not need a width attribute, the width scales proportionately as the browser window size is changed.

And this little gem, is in case the image is scaled up, it will not look (overly) blocky (it interpolates).

```
img { -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic; }
```

Props go to this source:
[Ultimate IE6 Cheatsheet: How To Fix 25+ Internet Explorer 6 Bugs](http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs#one-hundred-percent-height)

Comment: or ```style="height: 80%; image-rendering: pixelated;"``` for chrome (or other interpolation methods if needed, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering)

Answer (score 7):

Adding `max-width: 100%;` to the `img` tag works for me.

Answer (score 3):

I think the best solution is resize the images via script or locally and upload them again.
Remember, you're forcing your viewers to download larger files than they need

Answer (score 3):

For an automatic letterbox/pillarbox in a fixed-size rectangle, use the `object-fit` CSS property.  That is usually what I want, and it avoids using code to figure out which is the dominant dimension or — what I used to do — embedding an `<SVG>` element with an `<image>` child to wrap the content with its nice `preserveAspectRatio` options.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      :root
      {
        --box-side : min( 42vmin, 480px ) ;
      }
      body
      {
        align-items : center ;
        display : flex ; 
        flex-wrap : wrap ;
        justify-content : center ;
      }
      body,html
      {
        height : 100% ;
        width : 100% ;
      }
      img
      {
        background : grey ;
        border : 1px solid black ;
        height : var( --box-side ) ;
        object-fit : contain ;
        width : var( --box-side ) ;
      }
    </style>
    <title>object-fit</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="https://alesmith.com/wp-content/uploads/logos/ALESMITH-MasterLogoShadow01-MULTI-A.png" />
    <img src="https://ballastpoint.com/wp-content/themes/ballastpoint/assets/img/bp-logo-color.svg" />
    <img src="https://d2lchr2s24ssh5.cloudfront.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/GF19_PrimaryLogo_RGB.png" />
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/paradeigm-social/NeFAAJ7RlCreLCi9Uk9u_pizza-port-logo.svg">
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/lostabbey-prod/Logos/Logo_Port_SM_Circle_White.png" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I know how to do this, is:

1) set overflow to scroll and that way the image would stay in but you can scroll to see it instead

2) upload a smaller image. Now there are plenty of programs out there when uploading (you'll need something like PHP or .net to do this btw) you can have it auto scale.

3) Living with it and setting the width and height, this although will make it look distorted but the right size will still result in the user having to download the full-sized image.

Good luck!