# PHP echo syntax, to scale an image

Tags: php, html, sql-server

I have the following syntax:

```
echo "<img src=\"images2/" . $row['image']  . "\" alt=\"\" /><br />"; }
```

I would like to a give a specific height and width for the image, but I can't to do it.

Comment: `height="XXXX" width="YYY"` ?

Comment: Have you made any research? Have you tried to google? What search requests have you used?

Comment: `style="height: 30px"`?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1347675/html-img-scaling

Comment: sorry for the typo, it should be in it

Comment: You have a number of syntactical errors (related to escaping quotes) that will need to be resolved before your markup can be correctly rendered. Several of the answers below demonstrate ways to fix these typos.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify dimensions directly in your HTML `<img>` tag:

```
echo "<img src=\"images2/\" . $row['image']  . "\" alt=\"\" height=\"100\" width=\"100\" /><br />";
```

Note that your posted code has a closing curly brace (`}`) following your `echo` statement, which will cause a PHP error if there's no corresponding opening curly brace. You're also incorrectly escaping the double-quotes after `images2/`, which will result in invalid markup.

A better approach would be to enclose your entire markup in single quotes so that you don't have to escape the double quotes enclosed within:

```
echo '<img src="images2/' . $row['image'] . '" alt="" height="100" width="100" /><br />';
```

EDIT:

For modern day markup (depending on your requirements), it's considered vastly preferable to modify image dimensions in CSS, rather than in your `<img>` tag. You may want to consider implementing something akin to the following:

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    img.large {
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
    }
</style>

<?php

    echo '<img src="images2/' . $row['image'] . '" alt="" /><br />'; // no class attribute, so will default to 100x100  
    echo '<img src="images2/' . $row['image'] . '" alt="" class="large" /><br />'; // class attribute is `large`, so will rescale to 200x200
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
echo '<img src="images2"'.$row['image'].'\ alt="" width="" height="" /><br />'; }
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do?